# create a preview of html page with input passed by user

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a html page in witch a user can insert data with input type text or textarea. he can press a preview button for create a preview. When he press the button, the preview has to opened in other page.
For realize this, I thought to create a fake html page with data passed by user. someone knows how to pass data in other html page with js?

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="title" value="" onclick="" />
<textarea id="text" onclick=""> </textarea>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var title= $('title')
  var text= $('text')

  //open another page with this data
});
```

Comment: Well for starters you're getting the values of your form elements incorrectly. `$('title')` should be `$('#title')` and `$('text')` should be `$('#text')`

Comment: sorry, my mistake

Comment: How about just using query parameters in a GET form? You won't need JS or jQuery.

Comment: how can I do it? I do not have much experience with GET/POST forms

Answer (score 1):

Use localStorage, sessionStorage, or if it were me, I would use window.open without a url in combination with jquery to simply build the second page from the first page.

You can see the a [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/N_Ate/op238ky4/title:).

```
<input type="text" id="title" value="" onclick="" />
</br /> body:
<textarea id="body" onclick=""> </textarea>
<br />
<button class="open-write">
    show page (document.write)
</button>
</br />
<button class="open-jquery">
    show page (jquery)
</button>

$('.open-write').on('click', function() {
    let title = $('#title').val();
    let body = $('#body').val();
    let handle = window.open();
    handle.document.write(body);
    handle.document.title = title;
});
$('.open-jquery').on('click', function() {
    let title = $('#title').val();
    let body = $('#body').val();
    let handle = window.open();
    let $body = $(handle.document.body);
    $body.html(body);
    handle.document.title = title;
});
```

Note: this will parse and execute javascript.

Comment: windows.open was the method I was looking for. but how can I combine this method with jquery? first I have to write the data on a page I created. so I have to open this page with windows.open

Comment: this is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to dynamically display HTML content in a popup window.

```
$('<div />').html('hello there').dialog();
```

The html function is where your content would go.